# Formatting results from SQL in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom SQL query that I run with this line:

```
@avg_score = "#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(@avg_score_SQL)}"
```

when that is run, @avg_score has a value of:

```
[{"score"=>8, 0=>8}]
```

the results are correct, but it prints it like that :-/  I just want it to print out the "8"

How do I get it to just print the value of score?

Comment: try select_one instead of execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[{"score"=>8, 0=>8}]` is just an array with one element, and that element is a hash. So you can access the score like this:

```
@avg_score[0]['score']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use execute method,  you have to free the Result object after you're done using it.
Also your statement can be used without quotes.
if you always have 1 result row, you should better use selecy_one

```
@avg_score = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_one(@avg_score_SQL)['score']
```